# Calling function variable/name info

Tags: c++

```
int a(int p){

return ++p;
};

int main(){
a(???);
return 0;
};
```

what do you write inside the parentheses? well....an example??? what's the purpose of putting a new name when calling?

(I am not sure how to explain exactly what I mean it is quite a general question..?) an explanation would be nice. I know I can write in "time","price" for example, but why cant I just use p?

Comment: `void main` is not legal C++. The return type must be `int`.

Comment: Also, when you call a global variable inside a function...why is a storage class required? the auto storage class gives automatic storage duration why would something with static storage duration and a name with program scope require a storage class????

Comment: in the visualbasic debugger it shows no problem? when i compile the program it will be a problem?

Comment: It's not valid C++. Compilation is required to fail.

Comment: alright...if i do make it int main()....when i return 1? does that mean EXIT_FAILURE if 0 means the opposite?

Comment: The only fully portable things to return from `main()` are `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS` (these two are equivalent) and `EXIT_FAILURE`. Everything else, including `1`, is implementation-defined. In C99 and later, you can even leave the `return` statement out altogether (*only* for the `main()` function) and it'll implicitly `return 0` for you.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, All good except that this is C++, so s/C99/either C++ or C++03. I'm not sure if C++98 let you leave it out, but I think it did.

Comment: @chris: Yeah, I noticed the C++ tag after leaving that comment.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, Well, I can say the return values are the same story. I recently looked it up in both standards to make sure :p

Comment: " (these two are equivalent) "...when you say that do you mean return 0 is equivalent to exit success and failure? either or? or is it just success?

Comment: so return 0 means exit_success/and-or/exit_failure

Comment: I mean that `return 0` and `return EXIT_SUCCESS` are equivalent, and both indicate a successful termination. `return EXIT_FAILURE` is the only strictly conforming way to indicate an unsuccessful termination when returning from `main()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `p` because `p` is not in scope at the point you call the function - in your code, `p` is local to `a()`.

You could use `p` if you did something like:

```
int a(int p){
    return ++p;
};

int main(void) {
    int p = 4;
    int p_plus_one = a(p);
    return 0;
};
```

because they're both local to their own scopes, and don't collide.

Comment: do you have to add void to parameters or can you just leave it empty?

Comment: In C++, `()` and `(void)` are equivalent in this context, it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Also, when you call a global variable inside a function...why is a storage class required? the auto storage class gives automatic storage duration why would something with static storage duration and a name with program scope require a storage class????

Comment: There's no such thing as "calling a variable". Anything outside of a function has static storage duration, since there is no surrounding block to which an automatic storage duration could be limited. When you add a `static` qualifier to a file-scope variable, you're giving it static *linkage*, not static *duration*. The use of the same term for two different things is somewhat unfortunate.

Comment: I was referring to the properties of the global variable...it has STATIC STORAGE DURATION and the name has external linkage. I did not mean giving it internal linkage.

Comment: All global variables have static storage duration. I'm not sure what you mean by "why is a storage class required?" It's not "required", it just has one.

Comment: maybe thats a visualbasic command error issue...when I refer to the name it saids storage class required...I guess that;s a compiler thing?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what you might be doing running C++ within Visual Basic.

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing like you need to use a new name for passing the parameters into the function

you can pass any `integer` variable of your choice into the function `a()`

**Example:**

if you have a variable `p` declared this way , you can pass it also :

```
int main(){
int p = 50 ; //some integer value (it's necessary that the variable should be assigned a value)
a(p);
return 0;
};
```

or else if you have a variable `time` declared this way , you can pass it also :

```
int main(){
int time = 60 ; //some integer value (it's necessary that the variable should be assigned a value)
a(time);
return 0;
};
```

Comment: Probably best not to give a variable the same name as a standard library function, though.

Comment: yeah.. but i did so just to clear his doubt @PaulGriffiths

Comment: would those be considered passing by value?